# Custom AlertDialog - problem with android.R.id.custom

Tags: android

I'm sure I'm missing the point here so I'm hoping someone can explain.

I want to create a popup when a user touches an `ImageView`. I had a look at `AlertDialog` and the docs say...

> If you want to display a more complex view, look up the FrameLayout called "custom" and add your view to it:

...with the following code...

```
    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
    fl.addView(myView, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
```

So as a test I tried the following in my onCLick() method...

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello World");
    FrameLayout customFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
    customFrameLayout.addView(tv, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The last line of the above where I'm calling `addView` throws a `NullPointerException` which makes me think there's a problem with `android.R.id.custom`.

So the question is, what is wrong with the above and also is there a better way of creating a custom popup (perhaps by using the `Dialog` class or extending it)?

NOTE: I'm only using `TextView` in this example as a test, I want to add something more complex for my actual popup.

Comment: Use AlertDialog.setView(View view) to add a custom view to an AlertDialog. Check out [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28801551).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create an `Activity` and style it using the dialog theme:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

See [applying themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for more information.

Comment: This looks like a much better way to do what I need using startActivityForResult() - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Mossila's AlertDialog customization examples. I found them more helpful than Google's examples.

I cut-and-pasted Mossila's code directly into my project and it just worked:-)  Then I made a few tweaks to meet my needs.

http://mossila.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/android-dialog-single-choice-items/

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is because you dont "inflate" the layout. With a FrameLayout you need to use the `LayoutInflater`

use the following code:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.id.custom, this, true)
```

This should work with FrameLayout. Read up more about this at the [Android Layout tricks page](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

Also check out [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

edit: i have noticed aswell that there is an identical article to this problem here too: [How to implement a custom AlertDialog View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view)

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't able to get things to work the way I wanted with an AlertDialog but I see now how to handle FrameLayouts properley.

Comment: you can't inflate an ID.  You would need an R.layout value for this to work.