# Dialog Box doesn't expands its height

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I saw some post on stackoverflow to change the height and width of the dialog box but when i implemented that in my code the dialog box doesn't respond to it.
Here I'm attaching some snippet that i'm using for my dialog box.

Can you guys help me out to sort it out please !!!

Code Used

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(Inv.this);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.importdata, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    InventoryCount.this);

            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);            



            // Listener1 of promptsView 
            // Listener2 of promptsView 
            // Listener3 of promptsView 





            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Any Thing");
            alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(300, 900);            
            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I got my solution over here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907104/alertdialog-with-custom-view-resize-to-wrap-the-views-content

Thanks to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the layout dimensions directly setting the width and height params in your xml file layout/importdata.xml

Or change it programatically this way:

```
View view_instance = (View)findViewById(R.layout.importdata);
LayoutParams params = view_instance.getLayoutParams();
params.width = your_new_width;
params.height = your_new_height;
view_instance.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Mwssage")
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", null).show().getWindow().setLayout(300,900);
```

Or you can set wight and height with Builder, but after "show" method.

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned in the edited blog but instead of setLayout(300,900) i have been using setLayout(300,1200) and layout moves upward it doesn't expands vertically that i want. @
Azazellj Nevmerzhytskyi

Comment: if your device screen size is smaller than dialog size - it will have horizontal state.

Comment: Do you know how to expand my dialog box vertically??

Comment: Right now I'm using tab

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder
.setMessage("Message")
.setNeutralButton("ok",null)
.show().getWindow().
setLayout(displaymetrics.widthPixels / 3, displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2);
```

Comment: Tried but can't expand my dialogbuilder height.