# How can I get reference on TextView from XML layout in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a curious problem with getting reference on TextView, SeekBar and other widgets. My AlertDialog looks like this:

```
public class LineDialog extends AlertDialog {
private static SeekBar seekBar1, seekBar2, seekBar3;
private static TextView textView1, textview2, textView3;

protected LineDialog(final Context context, final DrawView drawView) {
    super(context);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_dialog, null);

    setView(dialogLayout);
    setTitle("Line properties");
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); // TODO Code crash here :(
    setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            seekBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek1);
            // some other code...
        }
    });
}
```

When I want get reference in Line where is

```
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Logcat send me an Error

```
requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

But when I get reference in onClick() method in LineDiealog(AlertDialog) everything works fine. Unfortunately this is too late, because I need this reference before LineDialog.show() is called...

Comment: what is there to down-vote, i dont get why -3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it there in your original code. You saved the View returned by `LayoutInflater`, so that's the one you should use when calling `findViewById()` so it must be `dialogLayout.findViewById(...)`. I was having the same issue myself and works like charm now.

Comment: excellent answer. I just missed that as well

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application) is an example of the custom AlertDialogbox and [How to implement a custom AlertDialog View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view)
you can see how to add the view to the alertdialogbox.

Comment: Thanks for link, but its little different situation. They have Dialog like inner class and they can call ' TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01)'. In my case doesnt exist any dialog instance because its in her constructor..

Answer (score 1):

You must either reference your textView by LinearLayout or by android:id in the xml file.

**LinearLayout example:**

```
LinearLayout mainLinear = new LinearLayout(this);
mainLinear.addView(textBox);
```

the add text to the box:

```
textBox.addText("This is the text to add to the text box");
```

**xml reference (you must create the text box in xml first!!!!):**

```
TextView text1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.NAME);
text1.setText("Hello please pick an option below");
```

The NAME portion must be replaced with the android:id name in the .xml file