# Show AlertDialog using Sherlock with the Holo theme?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Using Sherlock on Android 2.3.4:
I would like to show an `AlertDialog` containing:

1)A title

2)A content

3)2 buttons

I'm using the below **class**:

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends SherlockDialogFragment{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getSherlockActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Title")
               .setPositiveButton("Fire!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

in my **Activity** i'm calling :

```
MyAlertDialog m = new MyAlertDialog();
m.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "hey");
```

It is showing the AlertDialog but with the old theme(Remember i'm using Android 2.3.4)

Here is my entire main activity  class if you want:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar ab;
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setTitle("Testing Sherlock"); 

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_one:
            MyAlertDialog m = new MyAlertDialog();
            m.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "hey");
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The style i'm setting for my app is:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
</resources>
```

P.S: I have the `ActionBar` displayed and everything is working fine except the theme of `AlertDialog`. 
I want it to appear like this one:

[image]

and not like this one:

[image]

Comment: Have you added the `HoloEverywhere` library as well?

Comment: No... should I add it?

Comment: That's the easy way to get the whole Holo theme on all API versions.

Comment: should I include it with sherlock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create Style:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyFragment">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In your SherlockFragmentActivity:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.MyFragment);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        ....
    }
}
```

**R.style.MyFragment** is the style.

**R.style.custom_layout** is your custom layout for AlertDialog.

Comment: the CTOR you've used for the builder is available only from API11 . also, even if you use AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MyFragment)); , it won't work. tested on galaxy s2 with android 2.3.5 .

Answer (score 4):

This library looks good for holo style android dialogs
https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs

[image: android styled dialogs]

Answer (score 1):

I have already done this, I don't remember the exact steps I took, but the general approach is:

Copy the XML alert_dialog_holo (I think that is the name) from:
 android sdk folder\platforms\android-version using holo\data\res\layout
to your project.

I think you have to make some changes in order to make it work correctly (I don't know anymore what I have done exactly, but I believe to remember you must remove the "android:" prefix from some style definitions, then they will be recognized by ABS.

Maybe you also need styles generated from this [tool](http://android-holo-colors.com/), but I don't know if they are implied to make it work.

Also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view) the corresponding answers will lead you the way how to inflate your own XML in your Dialog

Comment: you need to make some changes to the XML you have copied, so that it will work correctly, then you should be able to inflate the XML in the DialogFragment

Comment: That would be my alternative choice as I want it to simply work with Sherlock. I don't want to make my own new "Sherlock" class.. haha

Comment: you don't need to make a custom class just use your AlertDialog class and inflate the custom layout instead of androids standard layout

Comment: see the last sentence of my answer I have updated it, the link will hint you how inflate your layout