# how to set the button to the right in alertdialog

Tags: android

```
            Dialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraActivity.this).
                    setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                    setTitle("test").
                    setSingleChoiceItems(strs, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            }).create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

Above is my code and this is my result which shows below.
[image]

But I want the words shows at the left and the radiobutton shows in the right.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a list view and then inflate that view to alertdialog whilst using an array adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrayAdapter with a custom item layout and change the checkMark with your own : 
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"

Probably duplicate of : 
[Android AlertDialog.Builder setSingleChoiceItems with custom cell style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762958/android-alertdialog-builder-setsinglechoiceitems-with-custom-cell-style)