# Android SingleChoice AlertDialog is not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, apk, android-alertdialog

[image]

Can anyone help me please ? I want to remove the space (mentioned in the picture) between the choice circles and choice text for each item. I mean I'm going to stick the text of each choice to the circles . For this I have one method that is recalled in onCreate() method . Tnx in advance . Here is my code:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
    {
        Locale fa = new Locale ( "fa" );
        Locale.setDefault ( fa );

        Configuration config = new Configuration ();
        config.locale = fa;
        getApplicationContext ().getResources ().updateConfiguration ( config, getApplicationContext ().getResources ().getDisplayMetrics () );
    }
   //fa is a Rtl language
    getWindow ().setFlags ( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );

    alert();
}

 public void alert() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ad.setTitle(" چته ؟ ");
    ad.setCancelable(false);

    ad.setSingleChoiceItems(mylist, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you choose : " + mylist[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    ad.setPositiveButton(" تایید ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you confirm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });


    ad.setNegativeButton(" انصراف ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you canceled it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = ad.create();
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button pos = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Button neg = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
             alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(1000,800);
            pos.setTextSize(18f);
            neg.setTextSize(18f);

        }
    });

   alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking on other questions on stackoverflow I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24955344/5251245) that may help you.
Then adjust gravity and padding to achieve the wanted result.