# AlertDialog need a solution

Tags: android

I am new to programming, and so maybe the question is stupid. Searching the internet, but not found. I need to do so, as pictured. In one line, add Label and EditText. Help me please.

```
public void onAddExpenseClick(View viev){
      final String[] mChoose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mChoose);
      final EditText input = new EditText(this);
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.addExpensTitle)
                .setCancelable(false)

           .setView(input)
          .setPositiveButton(R.string.addExpensPB, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(input.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Enter the correct amount",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                Expense expense = new Expense();

                expense.setType(getTag(mChoose[itemChoosed]).toLowerCase());
                expense.setAmount((long)(100 * Double.valueOf(input.getText().toString())));
                expense.setDateAndTime(dateValue);
                try {
                    expense.setTripId(((TravelApp)getApplication()).getTripManager().getDefaultTripId());
                    //Log.d(LOG, expense.toString());
                    expense.setCurrencyCode(
                            ((TravelApp)getApplication()).getCurrencyManager().getEntranceCurrency()
                            );
                    ((TravelApp)getApplication()).getExpenseManager().create(expense);

                    tabFragment.gotoGridView();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.AdminDialogNB, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        })

        .setSingleChoiceItems(mChoose, -1,
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                          int item) {
                     itemChoosed = item;
                  }
              });
        builder.show();

  }
```

[image]

Comment: FYI: You didn't need to delete your old question. You could have edited with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your moving in the right direction.

[How to implement a custom AlertDialog View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view)

You need to create a custom view and make sure to inflate it.

Another link that provides a good tutorial.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/