# How to make this beautiful Dialog?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dialog, customdialog

I've seen this dialog, it's very beautiful. How can I make a dialog like this ? I've made some dialogs but with the default android theme, what theme I should use or where I can find other themes for dialogs?

[image]

Comment: Make a activity with dialog theme and custom layout it is the simplest way to do this..

Answer (score 4):

The picture you pasted in your question is actually a screenshot from a tutorial on how to create such a dialog. Simply follow the steps provided here: http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/10/android-dialog-android-custom-dialog-for-user-login.html

Comment: I download it from the site you mentioned , it's not the same dialog ,I think different version of api will show a different thing ,

Answer (score 2):

Best way will be creating you own layout for dialog
[Custiom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

[Google Ref](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

And you will have more control of your dialog behiaviour, good practice is to use Dialog Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

To create a beautiful dialog in Android,

- Use a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and inflate a custom view. (or)
- [Inflate a custom view for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view) and [customize the AlertDialog Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog).

> A fragment that displays a dialog window, floating on top of its
>   activity's window. Override onCreateDialog(Bundle) to create an
>   entirely custom dialog,such as an AlertDialog, with its own content...

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) will give you a clear picture about Dialog creation,design and tips.

Answer (score 0):

If possible its better to do by using Custom Dialog or Use activity with theme dialog.

```
<activity android:name=".MyDialog" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

Comment: this is the default theme and it's not what I want .