# AlertDialog with x amount of buttons decided at runtime

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to produce an alert diaglog with x amount of buttons.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Please select the correct AltCode");

                String btns = "";

                for(iPrepack i : prepackList)
                {
                btns = btns + "\"" + i.getAltcode() + "\",";
                }

                btns = btns.substring(0, btns.length() -1);

                builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
                        {btns}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        pp = prepackList.get(which);
                        populatescreen(pp);
                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();
```

The issue I have is that I just get one button displayed with all my altcodes, how can I seperate these into separate buttons?

Comment: You need to make a custom layout. This post might help you <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view>

Comment: I managed this without a custom layout, see my post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone gets stuck on this in the future

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Please select the correct AltCode");


                List<String> acodes = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (iPrepack i : prepackList) {
                    acodes.add(i.getAltcode());
                }
                final CharSequence[] btns = acodes.toArray(new CharSequence[acodes.size()]);

                builder.setItems(btns, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        pp = prepackList.get(which);
                        populatescreen(pp);
                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();
```