# Overlay Android AlertDialog with a View (Button)

Tags: java, android, button, android-alertdialog, material-design

I have created an AlertDialog (like below) and would like to display a View (floating action button from library) over it.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle("Last Day of School Description")
.setMessage(...)
.show();
```

It currently looks like this, but the dialog overlays the button. I want the button to be above the AlertDialog and clickable as well.
[image: Android Dialog Overlay]
My FloatingActonButton object is called "fab".

Comment: You need a custom view inside your alertdialog

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example or somewhere I can start?

Comment: @apoorvk if my answer helped, can you at least upvote it ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create your own custom view and attach it in your `AlertDialog` to have full control of the layout of the dialog itself

You can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view) for more info on how to implement a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom layout for dialog in order to include buttons of your choice. Below is the example of how you can make it work:

```
public void showCustomDialog(){
 try{
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(act);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout_fordialog); // your custom dialog layout
    d.setCancelable(false);


    TextView status = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.result_status);
    status.setText("Title of dialog");

    TextView msg = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.result_msg);
    msg.setText("body of dialog");

    Button ok = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.result_ok); // your button



    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do whatever you want here

        }
    });
    d.show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} // method end
```

**-EDIT-**

Please note that the above example is an alternative to `AlertDialog` . You cannot use this as a child view in `AlertDialog`

Comment: This is not working, my result is the button inside of the dialog, rather than in the bottom right hand corner.

Comment: @apoorvk please design the layout yourself, as how you want the dialog to be. Can't you design a layout in XML ? and then set the layout in `d.setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_FOR_DIALOG)` there is no rocket science behind it.

Comment: I already did, but my issue is that you cannot create a child view outside of the parent (dialog). Do you know any alternatives to make this work?

Comment: @apoorvk my solution above does not expect you to make this as a child in `AlertDialog` . Its an alternative for the whole `AlertDialog` just remove the `AlertDialog` code and call this `Dialog` instead... in My Case it works as I want, I have Vertical Buttons set to my custom layout..