# submit EditText and display result in AlertDialog TextView

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am very new to **Java** and I'm trying to keep things simple. Why doesn't this work? I have an XML layout with a `EditText` field and a `Submit Button`. I want to press it, an `AlertDialog` to pop up with the `TextView` of what I inputted into the `EditText`. What I tried keeps crashing:

```
        //CustomAlertDialogPopUp
public void submitButton(View v) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertXML, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Alert");
    alert.setView(alertLayout);

    AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();


    EditText text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alertText);
    String result = text1.getText().toString();
    text2.setText(result);

}
```

Sorry if I sound stupid! Like I say, super new.

Comment: What is the logcat output? We can't see why it is crashing

Comment: EditText text1 = (EditText) **alertLayout**.findViewById(R.id.inputText);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, this will work:

For custom AlertDialog view you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view)

```
public void submitButton(View v){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Message")
            .setMessage(text1.getText().toString())
            .setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```