# Find background view reference for default AlertDialog

Tags: android

I'm trying to find background view reference for a default AlertDialog. This is because I want to add a [BrokenWindow](https://github.com/zhanyongsheng/BrokenView) animation when the dialog is closed.
I browsed the layout for (holo) AlertDialog and the name of the id is @+id/parentPanel
How can I get this reference?
I cannot use findViewById(), since R.id.parentPanel is obviously not present in my resource.
Any other way than having a custom layout for my alert dialog?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

you should use a custom layout for your alert dialog. then you can use  `getView().findViewById(R.id.*your custom layout*);` to access. Its really simple to use a custom layout for your dialog and you can find out how in this post: [How to implement a custom AlertDialog View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view)

Comment: sure! please mark my answer correct if it helped your problem

Comment: I did, but my reputation is lower than 15 so the result is not displayed.