# Using Constraint Layout on Custom Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-alertdialog, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use a Constraint Layout for a custom Alert Dialog (god knows why, I always have trouble with them), and I can't get the view to display anything, unless there is at least ONE element who's layout_height is set to wrap content and NOT match constraint. Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/shapeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gH3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gV2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/gV1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gHBreak">

    </Spinner>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineSideLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineSideRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gH1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gH2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gHBreak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gH3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gH4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gH5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.60" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gV1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gV2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/shapeCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Shape"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gH1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gV1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineSideLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/colourCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Colour"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gH1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gV2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/gV1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/radiusCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Radius"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gH1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineSideRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/gV2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/lWCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Width/Height"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gH2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gV1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineSideLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gH1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/lengthCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Length"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gH2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gV2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/gV1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gH1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shapesText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Shape"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gH3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gV1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineSideLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gHBreak" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colourText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Colour"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gH4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gV1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineSideLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gH3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And Image:
[image: design]

And here is where the view is inflated:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter,null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

And this is what it looks like when I run it:
[image: runtime]

What am I doing wrong? I have

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

according to my build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your layout doesn't have any intrinsic height/width but relies upon the size of its parent through the `match_parent` height/width. Without specifying a parent in the inflation, there is no size available, so it defaults to zero. You will need to supply a parent as the second argument to

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter,null);
```

instead of the `null`.

I am not 100% sure what the approach should be. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2795324/6287910) to a Stack Overflow answer that outlines one approach.